# jQuery focusout event on form element is triggered even when child element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to trigger the focusout when the user is not focusing on the ENTIRE form element. But it shouldn't trigger when the user clicks on any of the form's inner elements like in this case the text field or the button. But it's being triggered regardless even though the event is bound to the entire form. How to resolve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/exutahfa/

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" />
    <button type="button">Click Me</button>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$('form').on('focusout', function() {
   alert('focus out');    
});
```

Comment: didn't understand what you trying to achieve?

Comment: I think you just need to stop the event from happening: http://jsfiddle.net/exutahfa/1/

Comment: Well, when you click on another element the focusout event gets triggered since the element you where focusing looses focus... It depends on your use case but I would give all the inputs a css class and listen to focusout on that class.

Comment: The issue here is that OP is clicking the submit button and that is technically not focused out of the form.

Comment: But in the OP's fiddle, clicking on the button is not triggering the focusout event for me

Comment: Click on the input field and then click the button.

Comment: Well that's what `focusout` does. When you click on input field form is gaining focus and then for clicking button, you're leaving input field which is essentially leaving the focus on the form, that's why event handler is fired. The issue is that you shouldn't try to register `focusout` event on form because a form on its own renders nothing the user can observe. All the input elements in the form are the ones which can attain and leave focus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because you are in-fact not focusing on the form, but rather on one of its **child** elements (input or button in your case). The `focusout` (or blur) event will bubble up to the `form` but is not triggered by it directly.

**You *might* want to:**

1. capture `blur` events on form inputs
2. see if another *child* element of the same form received focus

```auto
$('form').on('focusout', function () {
    var $elem = $(this);

    // let the browser set focus on the newly clicked elem before check
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (!$elem.find(':focus').length) {
            alert('focus out');
        }
    }, 0);
});
```

[Working example on JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/exutahfa/4/)

See how the form doesn't receive any focus in the linked fiddle: it it did, it would have been highlighted with a red border (see CSS definitions).

Comment: Could you explain why setTimeout is required?

Answer (score 1):

The focusout event doesn't work like that.

From the jQuery docs:

> This method is a shortcut for .on( "focusout", handler ) when passed arguments, and .trigger( "focusout" ) when no arguments are passed.
>
> **The focusout event is sent to an element when it, or any element inside of it, loses focus. This is distinct from the blur event in that it supports detecting the loss of focus on descendant elements (in other words, it supports event bubbling).**
>
> This event will likely be used together with the focusin event.

The reason the event in your fiddle is firing is because it detects the loss of focus on descendant elements. In general, I don't think the form element itself can even have focus, so calling `$('form').blur(function() { alert('focus lost') });` will not do what you want it to do either. You can, however, use `.blur()` on the inner elements on the form and have it work the same way if you are targeting specific elements and want them all to do distinct things.

As it stands, a form can't have focus, but its descendants can, and that is why you are running into the issue. If you are trying to call an event that changes the form when it is selected, then try adding a class to it the first time the user focuses on one of the input fields in the form, and then when they click anything else on the page that is not in the form, remove the class from the form.

Comment: @JánosWeisz, if you want to nitpick other answers and say `The latter should be done via comments.`, then I strongly suggest you read the placeholder text within the `Add Comment` box and notice that it makes mention to `Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid comments like “+1” or “thanks”.`, where by saying `+1` and `-1` has gone against said recommendation. Your comment neither suggests an improvement or asks for more information - although by saying - `The latter should be done via comments` - is correct, it is not your place to critique answers.

Comment: @BottledSmoke.. I suggest you remove this part `So, what exactly are you trying to do here?`, rest of the answer looks good to me :)

Comment: Oh no, I didn't mean that as an insult or a nitpick. I'm trying to get to what he wants to do with this event handler so that we can help him get to the solution he wants to arrive at. As it stands, the prompt is a bit vague, and I don't know if we can solve the problem with all the info so far.

I changed it to disambiguate it a bit.

Comment: It's not at all an insult :-) We usually post questions in comments and interpret our views in answer.. that's it

Comment: Ah I see where you're coming from. Consider that part redacted. 
:P

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply the focus out specifically to the elements you want it to work on and not all the form. Example:

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input id="focus" type="text" />  
    <button type="button">Click Me</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$( "#focus" ).on('focusout', function() {
   alert('focus out');    
});
```